# View list of Internet Explorer 9 Trusted Sites on Group-policy controlled Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, internet-explorer

I'm having issues running an ActiveX control in IE9 on a Windows 7 machine. Before I report the issue to the sysadmin, I wanted to check if the site was listed in the "Trusted sites" zone. I have *some* administrative privileges on this computer, so I can open the Sites list, I cannot scroll down to see the complete list of Trusted sites. Short of opening a trouble-ticket is there any other way I can get this complete list?

(I tried poking around in the registry, but didn't see anything relevant.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely in the registry, try this location:
**HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap**

or just do a registry search for a site or address that you KNOW is in trusted sites. that should get you there eventually.

Comment: Yep, thanks! I had to guess what the values meant, but I assume 1 is Intranet Zone, 2 is Trusted Zone, etc.

Comment: you guessed right